# error in executing lua code in vscode powershell terminal

Tags: powershell, lua, command

i normally execute my lua files in the terminal with `lua file-name.lua`. i recently found out that you could also execute the code from terminal using `lua53 .\file_name.lua` where the lua version was 5.3

the lua version that im using is 5.1 so i entered `lua51 .\file_name.lua` on my terminal but i was given this error instead

```
lua51 : The term 'lua51' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ lua51 .\main.lua
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lua51:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: i then renamed the executable lua file from `lua.exe` to `lua51.exe` and it worked without any error. i want to know if the error was due to matter of different names of the executable lua file.

Comment: Do you have `lua.exe` in your path?

Comment: Unless you were running the PowerShell console in the same directory as `lua.exe`, it's probably because it's not in your `PATH` as system variable.

Comment: @Vivere im quite new  so i dont know what is the path you are referring to. if you are talking about the path which contains lua file that i want to execute, then no `lua.exe` is not there and also there is no need to have it there it seems. all you have to have is lua downloaded on your system

Comment: @AbrahamZinala how do i run the powershell console in the same directory as `lua.exe`

Comment: `cd C:\Path\To\Lua`.

Answer (score 0):

> the lua version that im using is 5.1 so i entered

```
lua51 .\file_name.lua
```

on my terminal but i was given this error instead

> 

try to write this

```
lua5.1 .\file_name.lua
```

Comment: it did not work unfortunately